# Easiest way to count users running my application?

Tags: c++

So, I have a local c++ application which authenticates user credentials against a MySQL database. That's the only interaction it has with the outside, after that it runs locally.

I've never worked on this, and I couldn't find anything usefull (for now) about it. The question is what's the easiest way to count users running my app **LIVE**. This is to be displayed either on the website or on a discord bot, wherever.

Comment: Count the number of unique sign-ons in the last X hours as "active"?

Comment: Does your application "phone home" (talk to the DB) when it exits?

Comment: @NathanOliver no it doesn't.

Comment: @Botje I need it to be precise, within a couple of minutes since a user disconects, I want the counter to update.

Comment: Isn't this obviously impossible? If the application has no interaction with the outside world after initial login, then how could you possibly ever know when a user has stopped using it? I think you need to go over your approach again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know it is impossible right now. I tried making the database update every X minutes, and making the client update it aswell every Y minutes. But that caused performance issues on the client side.

I'm not asking how can I do it without outside world interaction (sorry if I explained myself wrong). Im asking for the simplest/most practical way to approach it.
Be it making the client go throught a tcp server or whatever.

Comment: What sort of performance issues? Clearly if you want this kind of information to be available on the server, to <X> seconds of resolution, then your applications need to phone-home every <X> seconds. If you don't want to or can't do that, then you ought to reconsider whether you really need this information.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The way I did it was forcing the database to update a row to 0 every 5 minutes (for example), and the client would do the opposite every Y minutes. So I would know the ammount of active users by counting the ammount of rows set to anything but 0.
This caused a little freeze on the client side everytime it tried to update the db.

Comment: @Soul "_This caused a little freeze on the client side everytime it tried to update the db._" Can't, such an update, be done in a separate thread, as not to impact the general workflow of the application?

Comment: When a user closes the application does he log out of the database? If so then you can just update the number before the user closes the app.

Comment: @Soul: Then you performed the task synchronously when you didn't need to! Sounds like your real question is how to perform <insert your manner of network communication here> without blocking your application's main functionality.

Comment: @kingW3 Even if that were the case you'd still need to account for crashes, message failures etc - generally not a good approach

Comment: @Soul The client shouldn't be touching database fields directly, and your approach sounds racy (what is the T=0 for server and client, respectively? is it the same?). Why not simply tell the server-side application "I'm here" and let the server-side application manage the database side of things? Probably by updating a timestamp for the client ID.